# What tasks is Spaun 2.0 able to perform?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling, nef, spa

According to "A Large-Scale Model of the Functioning Brain" by Eliasmith et al., Spaun 1.0 was able to perform 8 distinct cognitive tasks:

1. **Copy Drawing**: Given a randomly chosen handwritten digit, Spaun should produce the same digit written in the same style as the handwriting.
2. **Digit recognition**: Given a randomly chosen handwritten digit, Spaun should produce the same digit written in its default writing.
3. **N-arm bandit task**: Spaun should perform a three-armed bandit task, in which it must determine which of three possible choices generates the greatest stochastically generated reward. Reward contingencies can change from trial to trial.
4. **List memory**: Given a list of any length, Spaun should reproduce it.
5. **Counting**: Counting. Given a starting value and a count value, Spaun should write the final value (that is, the sum of the two values)
6. **Question answering**:  Given a list of numbers, Spaun should answer either one of two possible questions:

   i. What is in a given position in the list?

   ii. Given a kind of number, at what position is this number in the list?
7. **Rapid variable creation** Given example syntactic input/output patterns (e.g., 0 0 7 4 → 7 4; 0 0 2 4 → 2 4; etc.), Spaun should complete a novel pattern given only the input (e.g., 0 0 1 4 → ?)
8. **Fluid Induction** Spaun should perform a syntactic or semantic reasoning task that is isomorphic to the induction problems from the Raven’s Progressive Matrices (RPM) test for fluid intelligence

In "Spaun 2.0: Extending the World’s Largest Functional Brain Model" by Xuan Choo, it is written:

> The final Spaun 2.0 model consists of approximately 6.6 million
>   neurons, can perform 12 cognitive tasks, and has been demonstrated to
>   reproduce behavioural and neurological data observed in natural
>   cognitive agents.

What novel cognitive tasks does Spaun 2.0 add? Reading the thesis, I've only been able to identify:

1. **Adaptive arm control**: Given a force field applied to Spaun's arm, Spaun should adapt to the force and continue to be able to draw in spite of the changing environment dynamics.
2. **Stimulus matching task**: Given an example image from ImageNet, match other images of the same categories.

Hypothetically, instruction following could be considered as a task, but it seems like more of a meta-task, since it defines how Spaun can combine tasks to create new tasks without any architecture changes.

Comment: I understand if this question looks like shameless self-promotion, as this research comes from my lab. However, I keep honestly having to look this up and this seemed like a good place as any to post it publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting task numbers in Spaun becomes somewhat meaningless due to it's instruction following capabilities. However, the missing task was the **stimulus response task**, wherein given an image from ImageNet, classify it according to it's given identifier.